# WPF. Must have non-null value for 'Property' for multitrigger condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Have multitrigger, one of the conditions is not null, so if StowedAssetDetailedThumbnailViewModel != null then set template

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=StowedAssetDetailedThumbnailViewModel,
                                         Converter={StaticResource isNull}}"
                       Value="False"/>
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
    </MultiTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Using simple converter:

```
return isNull == null;
```

the error is 
**Must have non-null value for Property**

UPDATE:
Thanks, the final solution is

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                       Value="true" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=StowedAssetDetailedThumbnailViewModel,
                                 Converter={StaticResource isNull}}"
                                 Value="false"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Is it your custom control?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You'll want to use a MultiDataTrigger in this case.  A MultiTrigger can only be triggered by dependency properties.

Comment: The converse appears to be true as well... if triggering on DPs, you can only use `MultiTrigger`.

Comment: At least in some situations.